# Помогите разобраться, как поменять отображение даты в bootstrap-vue <b-datepicker> на числовой формат yyyy/mm/dd?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

[![

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<b-form-datepicker
    @input="onChangeDate"
    :state="isCorrectPeriod"
    value-as-date 
    size="sm"
    id="date-first-part-repo"
    v-model="form.SPCEX_DOC.document.selection_info.selection_info_rec.paying_date"
    :min="dateConstraints.min"
    type="date"
    placeholder="Выберите дату"
    >
</b-form-datepicker>
```

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNqSq.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNqSq.png)

Не нашла нужного свойства для изменения отображения даты в поле, может кто сталкивался с кастомизацией компонентов данной библиотеки? Bootstrap-vue

UPD: 
1. Использовать для форматирования даты :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }".
2. Если первый способ не сработал, проверить версию bootstrap, если устарела, то обновить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен props `dateFormatOptions`.

```
<b-form-datepicker
  id="datepicker-dateformat2"
  :dateFormatOptions="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
  locale="en"
></b-form-datepicker>
```

Выведет: `mm/dd/yyyy`

Подробнее читайте в [документации](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-datepicker/#form-datepicker).

Comment: спасибо! Такой вариант пробовала, не сработал. Но я нашла в чем ошибка, моя версия bootstrap устарела 2.1, а нужно 2.6)

Comment: Рад помочь :) @Nastya